# GAE, sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sqlite

Ok, I read a lot. There is many people with the same issue, but all answers was not helpful for me.

I'm trying to do this - http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/ , but each time I running the app, I have the same message:

```
> 2014-09-22 10:12:10 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8090', 'C:\\gae\\wp39']"
INFO     2014-09-22 10:12:12,089 devappserver2.py:725] Skipping SDK update check.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 82, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 78, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 970, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 963, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 768, in start
    request_data, storage_path, options, configuration)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 867, in _create_api_server
    default_gcs_bucket_name=options.default_gcs_bucket_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\api_server.py", line 364, in setup_stubs
    auto_id_policy=datastore_auto_id_policy)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastore\datastore_sqlite_stub.py", line 604, in __init__
    factory=sql_conn)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
2014-09-22 10:12:12 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Windows 8, Python27, GAE 1.9.11

1. I checked all permisions and started GAE as administrator.
2. I tried Compatibility Mode (XP&Me, Win7) - nothing.
3. I tried set TMP variable in app.yaml
4. I tried to find "datastore.db" on all C: drive - found nothing.
5. I tried start App from CMD (as Administrator), like this:

   - C:\gae\wp39>dev_appserver.py C:\gae\wp39
   - C:\gae\wp39>dev_appserver.py --datastore_path C:\temp\data.db C:\gae\wp39
   - C:\gae\wp39>dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore=yes --datastore_path C:\temp\data.db C:\gae\wp39

The same result.

When I try run app from console with attribute "--datastore_path C:\temp\data.db' , the system creates that file (about 9KB) , but still can't open database.

The folder "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\appengine.levalult" exists, but empty. I don't know what else to do.

Thanks. I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: have you tried to update your GAE SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve:

Change username to none Unicode or

Change the `tmp` and `temp` environment variable value to `e:\`  or

In the cmd prompt, do:

1. Change `env var` value

   Set temp=e:\

   Set tmp=e:\

   2: run gae

   `D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\launcher\GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe`

Reason:

In `datastore_sqllite_stub.py`,

In `def __init__`

Before the `self.__connection = sqlite3.connect:`

Add the following code:

```
    f = open( 'e:/tmp/a.log', 'w' )

    f.write( self.__datastore_file )

    f.write( '\n' )

    for name in os.environ.keys():

        f.write( '\n' )

        v = os.environ[name]  

        f.write( name ) 

        f.write( '   ' ) 

        f.write( v )

    f.close() 

self.__datastore_file = 'e:/tmp/datastore.db'
```

According to the code, the database file is located in:

```
c:\users\%username%\appdata\local\temp\appengine.xgogo\datastore.db
```

which equal to:

```
%TEMP%\ appengine.xgogo\datastore.db
```

Where the `%Temp%` is the environment variable.

When username have Unicode characters, make failed.